# How to run code that uses x86 IN and OUT I/O instructions?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I want to use the `out` and `in` instructions in my Assembly program to access a serial port, but these instructions are "privileged instructions".

My program should run in kernel mode for the CPU to be able to execute them.

Is there an easy way to run my program in kernel mode, or is the only way to do that is to create a device driver?

Comment: You don't need kernel mode.  You need the `iopl` system call to set your IO privilege level for whatever range of IO ports, so you can use `in` and `out` in user mode.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html

Comment: Oops, ioperm is the per-port one.  Use that if possible.  Or make read/write/ioctl system calls on `/dev/ttyS0` unless you're accessing the hardware directly as an exercise.

Comment: If you did want to run in actual kernel mode, you'd probably want to create a kernel module that starts your code as a kernel thread.  It's not particularly "easy", but it's separate from creating a device driver.  If you want your whole code to run in kernel mode, then you don't want it to provide an interface for user-space (an actual device driver).